# What if html has multiple images element and pointing to same resource then what is behaviour of the browsers

Tags: html, dom, browser

I have following HTML page,

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title> Test Page
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    <img src="myimg"  alt="img"/>
    ......
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in above HTML, An image element pointing to the same resource.

I want to know,

1. How browser behaviors in above condition?
2. Does browser get image only one time from a server?

I am just curious about performance

Comment: What exactly do you want to know in your first question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When multiple instances of same images are embedded in an HTML, does that load the image once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271484/when-multiple-instances-of-same-images-are-embedded-in-an-html-does-that-load-t)