# Force reload cached image with same url after dynamic DOM change

Tags: http-headers, single-page-application, browser-cache

I'm developping an angular2 application (single page application). My page is never "reloaded", but it's content changes according to user interactions.

I'm having some cache problems especially with images.

### Context :

My page contains an editable image list :

```
<ul>
<li><img src="myImageController/1"><a href="editPage/1">Edit</a></li>
<li><img src="myImageController/2"><a href="editPage/2">Edit</a></li>
<li><img src="myImageController/3"><a href="editPage/3">Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i want to edit an image (Edit link), my dom content is completly changed to show another angular component with a fileupload component.

The myImageController returns the LastModified header, and cache-control : no-cache and must-revalidate.

After a refresh (hit F5), my page does a request to get all img src, which is correct : if image has been modified, it is downloaded, if not, i just get a 304 which is fine.

*Note : my images are stored in database as blob fields.*

### Problem :

When my page content is dynamically reloaded with my single page app, containing img tags, the browser do not call a GET http request, but immediatly take image from cache. I assume this a browser optimization to avoid getting the same resource on the same page multiple times.

### Wrong solutions :

The first solution is to add something like ?time=(new Date()).getTime() to generate unique urls and avoid browser cache. This won't send the If-Modified-Since header in the request, and i will download my image every time completly.

Do a "real" refresh : the first page load in angular apps is quite slow, and i don't to refresh all.

### Tests

To simplify the problem, i trying to create a static html page containing 3 images with the exact same link to my controller : /myImageController/1. With the chrome developper tool, i can see that only one get request is called. If i manage to get mulitple server calls in this case, it would probably solve my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to show a picture in an img tag, with an optimal cache management, in a single page application.

Comment: Why do you need three consecutive requests of the same image?

Comment: Actually, it's not the same image, but the same uri (which a controller). If the file behind this uri has changed, i need to get the latest version of it.

Answer (score 1):

[5th version of HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) describes this behavior. Browser may reuse images regardless of cache related HTTP headers. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41636141/2594597) for more information. You probably need to use `XMLHttpRequest` and blobs. In this case you also need to consider Same-origin policy.

You can use following function to make sure user agent performs every request:

```
var downloadImage = function ( imgNode, url ) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) {
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        imgNode.src = blobUrl;
        // You can also use imgNode.onload callback to release blob resources.
        setTimeout(function () {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

For more information check [New Tricks in XMLHttpRequest2](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) article by Eric Bidelman, [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 4: Object URLs](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/31/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-4-object-urls/) article by Nicholas C. Zakas and [URL.createObjectURL() MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and [Same-origin policy MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Awesome, first solution that works (apparently everytime - and with good browser support) - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random ID trick. This changes the URL so that the browser reloads the image. Not that this can be done in the query parameters to force a full cache break or in the hash to allow the browser to re-validate the image from the cache (and avoid re-downloading it if unchanged).

```js
function reloadWithCache(img: HTMLImageElement, url: string) {
  img.src = url.replace(/#.*/, "") + "#" + Math.random();
}

function reloadBypassCache(img: HTMLImageElement, url: string) {
  let sep = img.indexOf("?") == -1? "?" : "&";
  img.src = url + sep + "nocache=" + Math.random()
}
```

Note that if you are using `reloadBypassCache` regularly you are better off fixing your cache headers. This function will always hit your origin server leading to higher running costs and making CDNs ineffective.