# How to set source of image in img tag to image object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to find out if I can achieve that `img` or `input` HTML can use image object data present in JavaScript variable.

```html
<input class="scroll" type="image" id="SCR_BoostWeapon" src="" title="Increase your sword skill" />
```

```js
$("#SCR_BoostWeapon").attr("src", SPRITE.SCR_BoostWeapon.src);
```

I can link the source of image in `<input>` to image object `SPRITE.SCR_BoostWeapon`, which was preloaded. However I can only link `src` property of the image object to `src` property of `input` element. Consequently, the browser loads the image again (from server or cache).

What I would like to achieve is to manipulate `input` or `img` HTML element to use image data already present in image object; not `src` but rather 'pointer' to image data.

Is this possible? If it is, how?

Comment: `SPRITE.SCR_BoostWeapon.src` debug it and check value of it. also input does not have `src` attribute `img` have and `src` attribute

Comment: @DevsiOdedra; I know the value of it. It's address. I can use it as src of img element. But that was not the question.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra `input type="image"` elements do have a `src` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image, although it's *very* outdated.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra; <input type="image"/> has src attribute.

Comment: simply, there is no concept of pointing an attribute value to an another tag's attribute - HTML do not behave like other programming. but take a lookhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271484/when-multiple-instances-of-same-images-are-embedded-in-an-html-does-that-load-t to know how image is re-used in HTML

Comment: @Garfield; thanks: I have set the cache. It bothers me that I can't do it more directly.